# How to deserialise JSON back to a class?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Ive got a class `Limits`. I am creating several instances of this class as I have other objects that each need a their own `Limits`. So when I am serializing all instances of Limits there are several entries in the json. In my example you will see I have `Thermo`. Imagine there could be `Thermo1`, `Thermo2` etc all in the json. I deserialise it, navigate to the instance I want and then convert it to `Limits`. But for some reason all `Min` & `Max` values end up being 0.

The class:

```
public class Limits
{
    Measured_I_ON_struct Measured_I_ON;

    Measured_I_OFF_struct Measured_I_OFF;
    Measured_V_ON_struct Measured_V_ON;
    Measured_V_OFF_struct Measured_V_OFF;

    public Limits()
    {
        Measured_I_ON = new Measured_I_ON_struct();
        Measured_I_OFF = new Measured_I_OFF_struct();
        Measured_V_ON = new Measured_V_ON_struct();
        Measured_V_OFF = new Measured_V_OFF_struct();
    }

    public struct Measured_I_ON_struct
    {
        public double Min;
        public double Max;
    }
    public struct Measured_I_OFF_struct
    {
        public double Min;
        public double Max;
    }
    public struct Measured_V_ON_struct
    {
        public double Min;
        public double Max;
    }
    public struct Measured_V_OFF_struct
    {
        public double Min;
        public double Max;
    }
}
```

I have a json as such :

```
  {"Thermo":{
  "Measured_V_ON": 
  {
      "Min" : 4.5,
      "Max" : 5.5
  },
  "Measured_V_OFF": {
      "Min" : 4.5,
      "Max" : 5.5
  },
  "Measured_I_ON": {
      "Min" : 4.5,
      "Max" : 5.5
  },
   "Measured_I_OFF": {
      "Min" : 0.15,
      "Max" : 0.22
  },
  }
  }
```

I am trying to deserialise the json back to an instance of the class Limits but the values inside each struct come out as 0.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("new 2.json");
JToken jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
jsonobject = jsonobject["Thermo"];
Limits limits = new Limits();
limits = jsonobject.ToObject<Limits>();
```

Everything inside limits has a value of 0. What am i missing here?

Comment: "But for some reason all values end up being 0." - all your fields are private. I suggest you create public writable properties. I'd also suggest you have a *single* `Limit` class (or struct if you really, really have to), rather than creating a separate struct for each property. Finally, I'd recommend renaming your properties to follow .NET naming conventions, using the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to specify the naming in JSON files if you need to.

Comment: @JonSkeet That did it. Thank you, cant believe I missed that. Been scratching my head for an hour and a half. Dont know whether I need coffee, or sleep. I realise this is beyond the scope of this OP. Could you please expand what you mean by have a single Limit class. How would I structure it then? So does JSONProperty attribute allow me to change the name of the keys during runtime when serializing?

Comment: You've got four `struct` types, all of which are exactly the same. I'm suggesting you should use a single type instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields are private, which is why they're not being changed.

I would change your code significantly though:

- Use a single type for all the limits, given that they're exactly the same.
- Use a class rather than a struct, to avoid creating a mutable struct. (You could potentially use a custom converter instead, but I think it's simpler to use a class.)
- Use public properties for the properties in the `Limits` rather than private fields
- Rename the properties to follow .NET naming conventions, using `[JsonProperty]` to specify the name you want in the JSON.

So something like this:

```cs
public class Limit
{
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
}

public class Limits
{
    // TODO: Rename these further to expand on "I" and "V" if possible

    [JsonProperty("Measured_I_ON")]
    public Limit MeasuredIOn { get; set; } = new Limit();

    [JsonProperty("Measured_I_OFF")]
    public Limit MeasuredIOff { get; set; } = new Limit();

    [JsonProperty("Measured_V_ON")]
    public Limit MeasuredVOn { get; set; } = new Limit();

    [JsonProperty("Measured_V_OFF")]
    public Limit MeasuredVOff { get; set; } = new Limit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package. It's very handy on Json parsing with C#.
You can write as below.

```
            string json = File.ReadAllText("new2.json");
            var jsonobject = JObject.Parse(json);
            var jsonBody = jsonobject["Thermo"].ToString();
            LimitsRoot limitsRoot = new LimitsRoot();
            limitsRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LimitsRoot>(jsonBody);
```

LimitsRoot related classes will look as below

```
public class MeasuredVON
    {
        public double Min { get; set; }
        public double Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeasuredVOFF
    {
        public double Min { get; set; }
        public double Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeasuredION
    {
        public double Min { get; set; }
        public double Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeasuredIOFF
    {
        public double Min { get; set; }
        public double Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class LimitsRoot
    {
        public MeasuredVON Measured_V_ON { get; set; }
        public MeasuredVOFF Measured_V_OFF { get; set; }
        public MeasuredION Measured_I_ON { get; set; }
        public MeasuredIOFF Measured_I_OFF { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can check by running you will get value correctly as below

*limitsRoot.Measured_V_ON.Min*

4.5